# How to get place Name of location from google.maps.Geocoder()?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3

I want to name of location from google Geocoder(). I have draggeble marker on Map, when I dragend marker, we will get position of marker by following code. 
 `geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());`

I am able to get the address of location, but how to get the name of location, like if you drage the marker on well known building like **white house**, it should give name of location as **white house**.

```
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      function geocodePosition(pos){
         geocoder.geocode({
            latLng: pos
         }, function(responses){
            if (responses && responses.length >0){
              $scope.address=responses[0].formatted_address;
              $scope.name=responses[0].address_components[0].long_name;
            } else{
              $scope.address='Cannot determine address at this location';
            }
         });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Geocoder is for translating **postal addresses** to coordinates.  The reverse geocoder does the reverse (translates coordinates to addresses).

If you need the name of the place (or if you want to include the name of the place along with the address), you need to use the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)